# Column not containing in range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I've been struggling with this one query:

```
Column A 
--
usa-persona
ind-personb
kor-personc
jpn-persond

Column B
-- 
usa-persona
ind-personb
ind-personb2
ind-personb3

Desired Output
--
ind-personb2
ind-personb3
```

1. Search through column B,
2. Return ones that have the string 'ind',
3. But they should not be in Column A.

This is what I have, which doesn't seem to do the last part (checking to see if they are in Column A).
QUERY(A:B, "SELECT B where B contains 'ind' and not B matches '"&A:A&"'"))
How do I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=filter( B2:B, search("ind", B2:B), isna(match(B2:B, A2:A, 0)) )`

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=FILTER(B1:B; NOT(COUNTIF(A1:A; B1:B)))
```

[image]